# Prove openness of $S$ := $\textstyle \prod_{i=1}^n(a_i,b_i) $

Tags: general-topology

I'm having trouble getting started. Can anyone help?

Consider the set $S$ := $\textstyle \prod_{i=1}^n(a_i,b_i) $ = { **x**= ($x_1,...,x_n) $ $\in\mathbb{R}^n|\forall{i}$  $ a_i < x_i < b_i$} $\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ with arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$, **a**= ($a_1,...,a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n $ and **b**=($b_1,...,b_n) \in\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the set $S$ is an open set. (Directly prove the claim without arguing the boundary.)

Comment: What is your definition of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? This question seems a bit circular to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If your only tool for showing that $S$ is open is showing that for each $\mathbf x\in S$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $$B(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)=\{\mathbf{y}\in\Bbb R^n:\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|<\epsilon\}\subseteq S\;,$$

try letting $$\epsilon=\min\big(\{x_i-a_i:i=1,\dots,n\}\cup\{b_i-x_i:i=1,\dots,n\}\big)\;.$$

(It may help to make a sketch or two for the case $n=2$ to see what’s going on with that choice of $\epsilon$.)

Comment: I dont understand how this set is a rectangle when n=2

Comment: @Nik: What set? $B(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)$ isn’t a rectangle, but $(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)$ obviously is one: just draw it.